# How to put applications in "Search your computer" after running fcsk?

Tags: 16.04, unity, unity-dash

after some weeks I installed Ubuntu 16.04, at the start-up I had a problem and so I run fsck on the partition.

This apparently solved my problem but now all the installed applications (even the default ones such as calculator) are not showing in the "Search your computer" window.

I tried the suggestions found in other posts such as `unity --reset`, `unity replace`, `unity --reset-icons` I tried to install some packages like zeitgeist, desktop-file-utils and so on but nothing solved.

My question does anyone have a suggestion to put back the application icons without creating manually each desktop file and without a fresh install of Ubuntu OS?

NOTE: there is no filter when I try to search any element.

Comment: Can you check that the respective .desktop files exist under `/usr/share/applications` or simply `locate *.desktop`? If you create a working .desktop yourself, does it show in Dash?

Comment: I can see for example vlc.desktop in /usr/share/applications but not with locate.

Comment: Do `sudo updatedb && locate *.desktop | grep vlc*` and report back

Comment: No it did not work even if I reboot. I had even tried to reinstall vlc but nothing.

Comment: I cant see a reason why you would see them with GUI but not in the terminal. Maybe you can try doing ls for that vlc .desktop